# draw icon from database

Tags: java, android, eclipse

ok i try to draw icon from database in a map... but i have null pointer exception..

i do this ..

```
public enum icon { lake }
```

[....]
     public class POI implements Serializable
     {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = -8618762943599351669L;

```
private long id;
private String name;
private double longitude;
private double latitude;
private boolean visible = true;
public static  String icon;
private String info;

public POI(long id, String name, double longitude, double latitude, boolean visible, String icon, String info)
{
    this(id, name, longitude, latitude, visible, icon, info, true);
}

public POI(long id, String name, double longitude, double latitude, boolean visible, String icon, String info, boolean b)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.visible = visible;
    POI.icon = icon;
    this.info = info;
}

void initOverlays()
{
    Map<icon, Bitmap> markersIcons = new HashMap<icon, Bitmap>();
    Bitmap posMarker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker);
    Bitmap pathMarker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dest);
    Bitmap church = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.church); 
    TilesManager tilesManager = mapView.getTilesManager();



    tracksOverlay = new TracksOverlay(this, tilesManager);
    positionMarkerOverlay = new PositionMarkerOverlay(tilesManager, posMarker);
    markersIcons.put(icon.church, church); 
    poiOverlay = new POIOverlay(tilesManager, this,  markersIcons);


    pathOverlay = new PathOverlay(tilesManager, pathMarker);

    mapView.addOverlay(tracksOverlay);
    mapView.addOverlay(poiOverlay);
    mapView.addOverlay(positionMarkerOverlay);
    mapView.addOverlay(pathOverlay);

    StateManager.restoreTracksOverlayState(this, tracksOverlay);
    StateManager.restorePOIOverlayState(this, poiOverlay);
    StateManager.restorePathOverlayState(this, pathOverlay);
}
```

after i draw icon from database i get in "lake" in colums of icon..

```
public POIOverlay(TilesManager tilesManager, Context context,Map<icon, Bitmap> poiMarker)
{
    super(tilesManager);

    this.context = context;

 this.setPoiMarker(poiMarker);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextSize(15);
}

@Override
protected void drawOverlay(Canvas canvas, int x, int y)
{
    for (POI poi : points)
    {
        if (!poi.isVisible()) continue;

        Point poiPos = tilesManager.lonLatToPixelXY(poi.getLongitude(), poi.getLatitude());
        int finalX = poiPos.x + x;
        int finalY = poiPos.y + y;
        Bitmap marker = markersIcons.get(POI.icon);


        canvas.drawBitmap(marker, finalX - marker.getWidth() / 2, finalY - marker.getHeight() / 2, bitmapPaint); 
        canvas.drawText(poi.getName(), finalX - marker.getWidth() / 2, finalY, textPaint);
    }
}
```

But i have null pointer from POI.icon i make breakpoints to debug and poi.icon is null not read string from database... why???? Need help!!